# Breaking symmetry in symmetric scales

Tags: theory

I'm new to music theory and I'm not sure whether this is the best title for the question.
I wonder if making an arbitrary (single) change (raising/lowering by a semitone) to any **single** note within a symmetric scale would always make the scale asymmetric.
E.g. will any arbitrary single change make a whole-tone scale into some asymmetric scale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious, intuitive answer is - yes it would.  A symmetric scale contains repeated interval patterns.  Modify one note, the pattern is broken.

I'm struggling to find an extreme case where this might not be true.  I don't think there is one.

Comment: If my back-of-the-napkin math is correct, the only possible case where altering the set of intervals in this way could potentially not break symmetry is the trivial "scale" of two notes (root+octave), and that changes the size of the scale. Taking any other set would require increasing the size of one interval and decreasing the size of another: